# Is there any api available in order to download an epub book in windows phone7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an application in which I am displaying list of books available online, whenever user selects any book it should be downloaded and displayed on the screen. How to write code for this?

Can we use `WebClient.DownloadFile()` or something similar which can solve the issue?

Comment: The same way you'd download anything else? Opening it might be another matter ...

Comment: As the epub is in zip format, do I first need to download an epub file then only I can unzip it? Please guide me int his.

Comment: My question is I have an application in which I am displaying list of books available online, whenever user selects any book it should be downloaded and displayed on the screen. How to write code for this. Can we use WebClient.DownloadFile() or something similar which can solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried using WebClient or HttpWebRequest?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the same capabilities to download content as with any other type of files (not only e-books).  `WebClient.OpenReadAsync` and the associated handlers will do.

The question here is - what is the file format for the e-books you are downloading? If those are PDFs, then you have only two choices here:

1. Have a web link to the file, so that it can be opened from the web
   browser and the Adobe Reader application will automatically pick it
   up.
2. Use a PDF reader control in your own application. It is not a
   part of the SDK and will require you to use a third-party control,
   [like this](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/PdfViewerPhone/).

Comment: Thank you for your guidance but how safe is using a third party tool. Because then the PDF part of the application will be dependent on that.

Comment: You are using a component that is a stand-alone entity. Yes, you depend on it, but it is not loaded from the web, so you don't have to worry about it stopping working at some point if you use it correctly and the OS supports it. As of stability, there is always a risk with third-party components.

Comment: The format for the e-books to download is epub with HTML files which is zipped. How to check that the link which I clicked to download is not a hyperlink and will not navigate futher? Also I am creating a directory in windows phone 7 using isolated storage file, so that I can save the downloads. Suggest me few links to refer, for writing code for downloading and unzipping epub files.